# How convert .jsx to .js with Gulp and Babel?

Tags: reactjs, gulp, babeljs

I need to convert all /src/*.jsx files to /src/*.js

Before I used gulp-react:

```
var react = require('gulp-react');

gulp.task('jsx', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/jsx/*.jsx')
   .pipe(react())
   .pipe(gulp.dest('src/js/'));
});
```

It works but not without some small mistakes.
When I use Babel website (https://babeljs.io/repl/) all converts right. Could you help me. How can I set gulp to convert .JSX files?

Comment: Seems like the documentation on Babel's website covers this: http://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#gulp And there are tons of resources already explaining how to use `gulp-rename`.

Comment: gulp.task('jsx', function () {
      return gulp.src('src/jsx/*.jsx')
        .pipe(babel())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/js/'));
    });

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say with that comment. Yep, that'll compile. Then you can rename with `gulp-rename`.

Answer (score 35):

First you need to install these two packages:

```
npm install gulp-babel babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx
```

then you can convert like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task("babel", function(){
    return gulp.src("src/jsx/*.jsx").
        pipe(babel({
            plugins: ['transform-react-jsx']
        })).
        pipe(gulp.dest("src/js/"));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, seemed like I needed `babel-core` installed as well.

Comment: This is such a useful answer. Lots of situations where someone *just* needs the JSX transformation and nothing else.

Comment: Hat to import @babel/core instead of babel-core. See: https://github.com/babel/gulp-babel/issues/124#issuecomment-326853222

Comment: Can you please add your package.json file also for this transformation.

Comment: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx it worked for me with latest version

Answer (score 6):

In order to get displayName automatically inserted on transformation, you need to install gulp-babel and [React preset](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/):

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-babel babel-preset-react
```

and then in the gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task("jsx", function(){
    return gulp.src("src/jsx/*.jsx")
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ["react"]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("src/js"));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

For latest **React v16.8.x** using **Babel 7**, use `@babel/preset-env` and `@babel/preset-react` modules.

```
npm i -D @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react
```

Then in your **gulpfile.js**:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task("whatever_task_name_you_prefer", function(){
    return gulp.src("src/jsx/*.jsx")
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
});
```

Comment: Don't forget the quotes — presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]

Answer (score 2):

```
gulp.task('build', ['copy'], function() {
    gulp.src([
            'src/**/*.jsx',
            'src/**/*.js',
            '!./node_modules/**'
        ])
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app'));
});
```

since I am also using ES6.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah using gulp with the package gulp-babel would do the trick.
https://github.com/babel/gulp-babel