# How to transpile React objects to DOM nodes?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, transpiler

### Problem and question

I'll made this code:

```
let el = (
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4">Username</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="username" />
    </div>
  </div>
);

document.body.append(el);
```

How could I convert this to this code:

```
let el = document.createElement('div');
el.classList.append('form-group');

let el1 = document.createElement('label');
// ... all attributes
el.appendChild(el1);

// ... Same with the div and the input tag inside the div.

document.body.append(el);
```

I'm using webpack and gulp in combination with Babel.

### What I've tried

If the [configuration of webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40188578/webpack-babel-couldnt-find-preset-es2015-relative-to-directory) is oke, I've got problems because webpack transpiles everything to this code:

```
var el = 
  React.createElement("div", { class: "form-control" },
    React.createElement("label", { class, "col-md-4" }), // ...
    React.createElement("div", { class, "col-md-8" }) // ...
      // ...
);

document.body.append(el); // <-- error happens on this line
```

This doesn't work because I don't use React and `el` is not a type of a `Node` and so the error is thrown.

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute `appendChild`  on `Node`: parameter 1 is not of type `Node`.

I just like the syntax of it. Same issue when I'm using it with [a gulp task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33243895/how-convert-jsx-to-js-with-gulp-and-babel)

Comment: But you have like static html string. Why wouldn't you simply use `let el = \`your plain old html string goes here\`; document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', el)`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko: I've tried your solution but I got this error: `insertAdjacentHtml is not a function`

Comment: `insertAdjacentHTML`